# read bits from pointer to array of unsigned char

Tags: c

Say I have an array of `unsigned char` of 6 bytes.
 
And some function modifies value in it. How would I retrieve modified values say from `0-19bit`?

```
void my_func()
{
   unsigned char tempVal[6] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0}
   unsigned char* temPtr = &temVal; // Say I am using pt
   int newVal;
   // call external function to modify value 
   // fun below assign new values to tempVal[0].. till tempVal[5].
   void someFuncTomodifyVal( tempPtr );     

   // Now I want values from say 1st19bits
   // how would I achieve that? I know I have to use And condtion with 7FFFF
   // so say somthing like

   newValue  =  *tempPtr & 0x7FFFF // but then *tempPtr will give me first byte only? 
}
```

So my question is what should I give instead of `*tempPtr` to get 1st 19 bits

example of

```
void someFuncTomodifyVal( unsigned char m[] )
{
   m[0] = 'some value retrieve from other funct'
   m[1] = ' values based on some cal'
   m[2] = ' values based on some cal'
}
```

Comment: You don't want or, you want and. Most portable way is to and, shift and or together the bits from the bytes you want.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, Thanks Mate , yes I need And . How would i Use array to And with 0x7FFFF

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show an example of input and expected output.

Comment: Bits 0 to 19 starting from the beginning or from the end of the `tempVal` array?

Comment: @MichaelWalz, functions inside calling func will modify tempVal[0] tempVal[1] etc

Comment: That (`someFuncTomodifyVal` function edit) is not an example. An example would be, for a given char array and mask, what actual specific output value do you want to see? At the moment I don't know how you expect endianness to work.

Comment: All I need is to how to use pointers with ''&" .

Comment: What is bit 0-19? You seem to make assumptions about a certain endianess.

Comment: Do you have bytes with more than 20 bits?

Comment: Yes bytes can be of 48bits . and its filled from right to left

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You probably intended to achieve something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
  unsigned char tempVal[6] = { 0x1,0x2,0x3,0x4,0,0 };
  uint32_t *temPtr = (uint32_t *)tempVal; // Say I am using pt
  uint32_t newVal = *temPtr;

  printf("%08x\n", newVal);
  newVal &= 0x7ffff;
  printf("%08x\n", newVal);
}
```

On a little endian system the output will be:

```
04030201
00030201
```

On a big endian system the output will be:

```
01020304
01020304
```

Be aware that this is **not portable** as it depends on the endianness of the target system and it also violates the [**strict aliasing rule**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

**Portable and correct solution:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
  unsigned char tempVal[6] = { 0x1,0x2,0x3,0x4,0,0 };

  uint32_t value = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    value <<= 8;
    value |= tempVal[i];
  }

  printf("%08x\n", value);
  value &= 0x7ffff;
  printf("%08x\n", value);
}
```

Comment: This violates the strict aliasing rule. Bad idea, don't teach this to newbies.

Comment: Also  newVal = *temPtr will assign only 1byte from array to newVal. I need 19bits

Comment: @samprat no, because `temPtr` is a `uint32_t*`.

Comment: @Lundin answer modified.

Comment: The modified answer makes a hard copy though, I'm not sure if this is what the OP wants?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is that you can't take a pointer to `unsigned char` and wildly cast it to a larger pointer type. This would result in a strict aliasing violation - undefined behavior. This can give incorrectly generated code and similar evil bugs.

To dodge this and access the array through a pointer, you could use a container type that contains the same type among its members:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef union
{
  unsigned char u8 [6];
  uint32_t u32;
} my_union_t;

int main()
{
  unsigned char tempVal[6] = { 0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44,0x55,0x66};
  my_union_t* mu = (my_union_t*)tempVal;
  printf("%"PRIx32"\n", mu->u32 & 0x7FFFF);
}
```

As for what this will print, it depends on CPU endianess - the code is not portable. On my 32 bit little endian CPU I get `32211`.

Comment: Actually he doesn't even cast it to a larger pointer type: `unsigned char* temPtr = &temVal`. Upvoted anyway.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yeah but obviously that won't work, since that will block the possibility to access the other bytes.

Comment: I'm just curious here, if you have time to look at [this solution](https://gist.github.com/hptk/5a89d6e7d74ba752b6e1831916630b06), is it also violating strict aliasing? I think it is if I understood it correctly.

Comment: @HansPetterTaugbølKragset Indeed it does, it is an almost identical case.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks :)

Comment: `(my_union_t*)tempVal` may fail as `my_union_t` and `tempVal` do not have the same alignment requirements.

Comment: Perhaps `unsigned char tempVal[6]` --> `my_union_t tempVal`?

Comment: @chux Good point, indeed the best solution is to ditch the raw array and only use the union. Alternatively toss in some asserts for alignment checks.

Answer (score -2):

**Wrong answer**

You can use a type which can store the 19 bits. Example : `uint32_t *n = (uint32_t *) tempVal;`. Now you can get the desired bits `(*n) & 0x7FFFF`

---

**Good answer**

You can use union to respect strict aliasing :

```
union foo {
    unsigned char   tmp[6];
    unsigned int    n;
};
```

Comment: This violates the strict aliasing rule. Bad idea, don't teach this to newbies.

Comment: Given `unsigned char tempVal[6]`, `uint32_t *n = (uint32_t *) tempVal;` then `(*n) & 0x7FFFF` violates strict aliasing.